# What is vanilla PHP? Is it different from the Vanilla framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

Is it a framework which is in the link *https://vanillaforums.com/en/software/*?

What is the explanation? What are some links?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Vanilla PHP is PHP itself.

In general, the term `vanilla <software>` means `<software> without any additions or customization`; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software) link.

The Vanilla framework is just a framework named `Vanilla`.

*Vanilla PHP* and the *Vanilla framework* are two completely different things.

Answer (score -1):

"Vanilla" term born as a joke against the framework trend. Many people during the job interviews usually say yes to any framework request.

I don't remember the name of a fake php framework used to have fun of these kind of people.

For sure "vanilla JS" was made with the same reason - the description :
"*The Vanilla JS team maintains every byte of code in the framework and works hard each day to make sure it is small and intuitive. Who's using Vanilla JS?*"

there isn't a Vanilla team, neither a framework.

To answer your question : Vanilla PHP framework doesn't exist. Now the term Vanilla is improperly used during interviews to refer to a plain language.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34704094)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

To sum up by the comments:

MyMomSaysIamSpecial :

> vanilla php is just PHP programming language itself.

aljo :

> Vanilla  means that  without anything else. Vanilla PHP just means plan original PHP without any framework.

axiac :

> As a general rule, the expression "vanilla " means that "" without any addition or customization. Never heard the expression used with "PHP". In this case, "Vanilla" doesn't mean anything; it is the name of the software. Check it out here: github.com/vanilla.